# Upgrading a native library does not work on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an application that uses a native library (.so).
In the new version of the application I made changes in the lib. The problem is that after upgrading the application it looks like the new library is not loaded.
If I force stop the application and then I restarted it everything works fine. 
In some cases just waiting for a while (for example 20 mins) fixes the problem.

Did anyone experience this issue?
Is there a way to fix it?

**EDIT**
I have also tried to call

```
System.loadLibrary("mylib.so");
```

in the onReceive of the OnUpgradeReceiver that is the broadcast receiver that is registered to be called when the application is upgraded
It did not help

**EDIT2**

I think this issue has to do with the fact that the lib uses the audio engine. The reason iwhy I think so is that I tried to change the name of the lib and it did not help either

Comment: So upgrading doesn't stop the application in the first place?

Comment: Does your **so** sit in the apk **/libs/armeabi** directory? You can easily check what exact version of the lib got packed into there: you can open an **apk** file as **zip**

Comment: @auselen What I could see is that I need to kill the application and restart it to make it working.

Comment: @Alex Cohn. The version of the lib is the correct one that's why when I restarted the application everything works

Comment: How are you installing the upgrade?

Comment: @ Chris Stratton I have uploaded the apks on the phone

Comment: You mean adb push? Then you need to kill it.

Comment: no what I did was to copy both apk on the phone by usb or from internet and then clicking on the file to install it

Comment: @herschel why are you writing about "apks"? Do you need more than one file to upgrade? Is your native library packaged in a separate apk?

Comment: @ Alex Cohn no the first apk is the old version the second the new one. SO I install the first version I make the lib being loaded and then I install the second apk. Please read the updated version of the question

Comment: Bottom line: the app needs to be restarted.  Executing System.loadLibrary() multiple times on the same library will have no effect.  For some reason the system isn't doing that for you; take a look at the logcat output while you're doing the install.

Comment: So you want to update so but not apk? and want to keep application running? If I update an application properly it always restarts. It is hard to understand if your problem is with updating or with so's behaviour? Updating app+so's work with Android, but you have to restart teh app to get it reloaded.

Comment: It's ok for me to restart the app the problem is that I thought the framework is supposed to do it. I'm not trying to restart the application programmatically at the end of the upgrading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok never mind I think the issue is just in my lib. I need to find where but I checked that the application is properly closed after the upgrading.